# React Native Linking with Secure Information

Tags: android, ios, react-native, authentication, react-native-linking

Note: this project is using **react native** and associated libraries and features.

## What I want to do:

In my application I want to allow a user to click a button; and that button will launch the native browser (Chrome or Safari) and navigate to a link associated with that button, while passing the users Authentication Token that was secured within the application behind Biometrics.

Note: I have control over the application and Website Endpoint, and so I can configure the endpoint to accept this Token and allow the user in without prompting them to log in.

It is my understanding that I could easily accomplish this by simply appending the Authentication Token to the end of the url via a query string.  This is insecure from my understanding.

## Security Concerns:

- Linking fires an intent on the device, don't all apps have the ability to read/log that intent?  Wouldn't that mean a malicious app could capture the linking intent (including the url and token) and compromise security?

## Question:

How do I use react native linking (Or another library) to have the device open the native browser, and then provide headers or information to that native browser that is not visible to all other applications?

## Possible Solution:

I could have my application submit the users token to a server side database; once I have done this I could pass a key or identifier via query string and retrieve the token from the database server side on the website.  This data could be encrypted; have a very short timeout; include a private handshake to verify requesting service; only respond to an (or a range of) IP addresses to reduce security risk, but this option is complicated and has multiple points of failure.  I am hoping for a more direction option.

## In Conclusion:

- Are my concerns with linking irrelevant?
- Is there an official solution for this problem?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi @Daniel; Sorry but no.  At work we decided this feature of passing security credentials to the native browser was not possible and/or not worth the work effort for our need.  Given what I've learned in the time since I posted this inquiry; I think the best possible solution is to utilize a Web Page hosted by you/your company; and use a backend system such as a database to hand off secure credentials; as described in the "Possible Solution"